# Ssh Socket Closed. Wanted an Interactive Ssh shell automation for Linux Box

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Ssh Socket Closed. Wanted an Interactive Ssh shell automation for Linux Box.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
##Creating Ssh Session

ssh.connect("gfr4123408", port=22, username='rstrusr',password='Password')


stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('symcfg -lockbox reset -ssv')

#Here it asks for password and i want to write password below

stdin.write("Password")

stdin.write('\n')

stdin.flush()

output=stdout.readlines()

print(output)
```

I Get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in
<module>
    stdin.write('password')   File "C:\Users\venkar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py",
line 402, in write
    self._write_all(data)   File "C:\Users\venkar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py",
line 519, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)   File "C:\Users\venkar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py",
line 1333, in _write
    self.channel.sendall(data)   File "C:\Users\venkar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py",
line 831, in sendall
    sent = self.send(s)   File "C:\Users\venkar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py",
line 785, in send
    return self._send(s, m)   File "C:\Users\venkar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py",
line 1169, in _send
    raise socket.error('Socket is closed') OSError: Socket is closed
```

How can I resolve this as I have to configure for 200+ Devices?

Comment: It seems like you really want [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/).

Comment: I got it I used channel.send in Paramiko Module . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you'll find useful:

1. `exec_command` takes an optional argument of `get_pty`. You can use it like this:

   ```
   (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command("sudo ls", get_pty = True)
   ```
2. Throw the password into `stdin`, with a line return and flush to make sure it gets delivered. This ensures it receives the password if it asks (you could do something more sophisticated to check if it actually asked or not... simply throwing it in always hasn't caused problems for me, yet.)

   ```
   stdin.write('passwd' + '\n')
   stdin.flush()
   ```

Taken together, those should fix your `sudo` over `paramiko` issues.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem is related to Time Between sending two commands.
I had this problem.when i used "time.sleep(X)" between my commands , this problem gone.