# how to source .sh file in python

Tags: python

I am basically doing python ssh connection code to my server which is basically a Ubuntu server 16.04.

Then I want to source this demo-openrc.sh file with almost 10 environment variables but 1 need user input which is basically a password but the problem is that when I source this .sh file in

```
> python -->In terminal-please enter your password
```

But it does not take user input and execute the next command is there any way how to resolve it thanks in advance.

What I am trying to do is:

1) python code to ssh my server.

2) source this demo-openrc.sh file after this file source successfully

3) I execute my next cmds like an OpenStack server list.

```
from _multiprocessing import send

import paramiko
import cmd
import time
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE


from paramiko import SSHClient
host="172.17.85.250"
user="stack"
passs="salman"
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user , password=passs)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./demo-openrc.sh')
print ("stderr: ", stderr.readlines())
print ("pwd: ", stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: can you basically add some of the code you wrote? It is hard to understand what you're doing otherwise.

Comment: @razdi this is what i do but not working it run all the commands but dint source the .sh file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read the password in your shell script from `stdin`, you could use [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to read the password in Python, and pass it to your script using `write` on the `stdin` of the [Paramiko Client](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/client.html).

Here is an example, based on your approach:

```
import os
from paramiko import SSHClient

host="[HOST}"
user="[USER]"
passs="[PASSWORD]"
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user , password=passs)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./demo-openrc.sh')
password = input('Please enter your password: ')
stdin.write(password + os.linesep)
print ("stderr: ", stderr.readlines())
print ("pwd: ", stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: Please enter your password: secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/salman/PycharmProjects/untitled/python-tut.py", line 9, in <module>
    stdin.write(password + os.linesep) File "C:\Users\salman\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1198, in _send
    raise socket.error("Socket is closed")
OSError: Socket is closed

Comment: Could you please try the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157084/ssh-socket-closed-wanted-an-interactive-ssh-shell-automation-for-linux-box)?